# Mounting SSD using PCIe adapter

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ssd, macbook, pcie

I recently purchased a generic (Chinese) SSD-to-PCIe adapter so I could read the SSD from my (broken) MacBook Pro. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and it seems to identify the hardware:

```
user@computer ~ $ lspci
01:00.0 SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9230 PCIe SATA 6Gb/s Controller (rev 11)
```

But I don't see anything related in `fstab` or `/dev` (like `/dev/sdc` or `/dev/nvme`). Running `lsblk` doesn't show the partition or drive either. I've read all the forum posts I can find, but they seem to focus on hardware that *isn't* recognized or items that appear in `/dev` but won't mount.

What do I do next? Is there a driver I should install for generic adapters?

**Edit:** Suggestion from @waltinator

```
dmesg --kernel --ctime --userspace --decode | grep pci\ 0000:01:00
kern  :debug : [Wed Jul 19 22:46:58 2017] pci 0000:01:00.0: [1b4b:9230] type 00 class 0x010601
kern  :debug : [Wed Jul 19 22:46:58 2017] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [io  0xe050-0xe057]
kern  :debug : [Wed Jul 19 22:46:58 2017] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x14: [io  0xe040-0xe043]
kern  :debug : [Wed Jul 19 22:46:58 2017] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x18: [io  0xe030-0xe037]
kern  :debug : [Wed Jul 19 22:46:58 2017] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x1c: [io  0xe020-0xe023]
kern  :debug : [Wed Jul 19 22:46:58 2017] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x20: [io  0xe000-0xe01f]
kern  :debug : [Wed Jul 19 22:46:58 2017] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x24: [mem 0xf7c10000-0xf7c107ff]
kern  :debug : [Wed Jul 19 22:46:58 2017] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xf7c00000-0xf7c0ffff pref]
kern  :debug : [Wed Jul 19 22:46:58 2017] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D3hot
kern  :info  : [Wed Jul 19 22:46:58 2017] pci 0000:01:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
```

Comment: Are you sure the SSD isn't also broken?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't have any reason to believe it's broken. Two reasons:
1. The Macbook was destroyed by a power supply failure, and all the magic smoke escaped. It's possible the SSD was damaged, but I'd like to exhaust all options before throwing in the towel.
2. I previously replaced the SSD when the first one was corrupted and could be read but wouldn't boot. I tried that one too, and it's producing the same results.

Comment: Shortly after you connect the disk, `dmesg --kernel --ctime --userspace --decode` should show you messages of interest.

Comment: Thanks @waltinator, I posted the results of the dmesg, with some grep filtering. Nothing seems out of place to me (?)